# IndexedDB object.put throwing ConstraintError

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have some javascript which returns an object from IndexedDB, then update some properties, and then tries to 'update' (well, add really) using put, however this throws a Constraint Error and I can't figure out why. The chunk of javascript looks like this:

```
indexedDbReturnRecord(AddressID, 'AddressID', 'AddressStore', function(retObject) {
    retObject.DateMovedIn = getDate();
    var dataToUpdate = new Array();
    dataToUpdate.push(retObject);
    indexedDbAddObject(dataToUpdate, 'AddressStore', function () {
        noCss();
        $('#CompleteBTN .ui-btn-text').text("Complete").button('refresh');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to provide some more information...

What is the definition of your objectstore?

The issue will probably be something with the configuration of the key on the object store and not providing it. Is see you are trying to save an array, and in this case I think you will have to use an external key.

Another possibility is issues with indexes on the store.

Comment: Ultimately the problem was down to a missing "keyPath" on the store.